# Forward declaration throws redefinition error

Tags: c, struct, compilation, typedef, header-files

I have two .h files and a .c file as below

## a.h

```
typedef struct mode_info_t_ mode_info_t;

struct common {
    int create;
    mode_info_t  *mode_info;
};
```

## b.h

```
typedef struct mode_info_t_ {
    int primary;
    int secondary;
} mode_info_t;
```

## main.c

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

-----
```

When .c is compiled it throws below error -

b.h:17: error: redefinition of typedef 'mode_info_t'
a.h:50: error: previous declaration of 'mode_info_t' was here

What is wrong here experts?

Comment: I'm not an expert with typedef but you're typedefing mode_info_t twice, once as another variable and once again as a structure ... what else to say?

Comment: It's exactly what the error says... you've redefined a type.  It's not the `struct mode_info_t_` though, but the `mode_info_t` you've typedef'ed to it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are right. One more thing is why doing `typedef` multiple times for the same structure. And also having a user defined data-type inside a structure?

Comment: how to do forward declaration for mode_info_t in a.h?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I don't have any error with this code.

Comment: Lines in error messages do not correspond to the actual lines from your posted example. You shall post a complete example where the problem is reproducible.

Comment: In b.h, try changing `typedef struct mode_info_t_ {` to just `struct mode_info_t_ {` (and drop the "mode_info_t" after the struct definition) so you define `struct mode_info_t_` without repeating the typedef for `mode_info_t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change b.h to this:

```
struct mode_info_t_ {
    int primary;
    int secondary;
};
```

If you need the typedef in b.h, have b.h include a.h.  If you don't want to have b.h include a.h but still need the typedef in both, then take the typedef out of a.h and put it in c.h, and have both a.h and b.h include c.h.

I've actually done this before where I put all my forward declarations in a separate header, just to avoid the need for various headers including each other when it wasn't totally appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I changed b.h to typedef struct mode_info_t_ {
    int primary;
    int secondary;
} mode_info;

Answer (score 0):

You have your b.h

```
typedef struct mode_info_t_ {
       int primary;
           int secondary;
}mode_info_t;
```

Then a.h

```
struct common {
       int create;
       mode_info_t *mode_info;
};
```

In your main.c just include b.h

```
 #include "b.h"
    #include "a.h"


    int main()
    {
    }
```

Comment: I cant do this way. Because a.h is included in many other c files where I do not want to expose b.h.

Comment: @Jithu Then do it the way shown in the edited version

Answer (score 0):

When I compile the snippet you have given, I didn't get any errors and warnings. Can you show us your full code? It is possible to declare a structure and after that you can define it.

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *nextptr;
};
```

Here you are doing the same thing. So it not an error. You may have mishandled it somewhere.